# Add fluent extension method to 3rd party class

Tags: typescript, extension-methods, zod

I'm using `zod` which allows to define some validation rules using fluent function.

Especially, one of the functionis `optional` which allows to declare a field as optional. Unfortunately, this function does not accept a flag to enable/disable the optional behavior. In my case, the form is built dynamically and the optional flag must be defined at run time.

I can create a small utility method to add this logic :

```js
import { z, ZodType} from 'zod';

const fieldIsRequired = true;

// Method 1 : wrapper / Working
const makeOptional = (input : ZodType, required : boolean): ZodType => required ? input : input.optional();

const entry1 = makeOptional(
    z
    .string()
    .min(10)
    .max(100)
    , !fieldIsRequired
);
```

This is working well, but I lost the *fluent* code. Having one rule is acceptable, but adding more rules will leads to a hamburger of function call and parameters

How can I add a new fluent function to the zod type, which come from a 3rd party lib ?

I've tried to implement extension methods, but I failed finding the correct syntax.

Here's what I tried :

```js
import { z, ZodType} from 'zod';

const fieldIsRequired = true;

// Method 2 : extension method / Not Working

declare namespace zod {
    export abstract class ZodType {
        makeOptional: (required: boolean)=> ZodType;
    }
}
// Add syntaxic sugar to the Zod schema
ZodType.prototype.makeOptional = function (required: boolean): ZodType {
    return required ? this : this.optional();
};

const entry2 =   
  z
    .string()
    .min(10)
    .max(100)
    .makeOptional(!fieldIsRequired);
```

How to fix this ?

Repro : [TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgLwDRwFoQCYBUCeYApgL5wBmUEIcA5MjrQNwBQLAxhAHYDO85wIgBtsASR4AlIgEcArsChFscALxwYUWUVYsA9LrgBZIjAAWOOAEY4ALjgB3KAEMwxKHAMB1aAGtgXAHMObj44ECcfIgB5MBhgbichVTgACn8wWXg7LDxCInRFOQUlWzgAIwgIISInLgBKbJwCYlUAPjhC+UVlAH44dMzSgZgAOghY+K5ElLqdTl54Ii4NfGs1cMiYuIShFJY4A5R9w5G+KH8AmeODkZB-FMsABjrruFunAA8Hx+fX9ABCATCMSSGRdJQsWZsPQGYxmCwAJlKRA+MCWPEmYRM5mUBgAchB4N4oH5AmxsER2EInIo4FMQEQeGAnOwiCgLAhXijILA4E4ymcWfAqU4eDxME08ohXocwhFohMdnYUp1itg7BUqjV6ip2jlmtpXiQWMb9HAAILYZQ8fDLT7AdhwHiyAI09QQdSmNk5J3sL3hFj6vIjMBUGCE4MbBXbKZJNTkWRcdgx1Kq7oayrVWoNCW5Fqc2WKGCyKBcDpgtVwPpmYDiuw1nhjRWxmasEhzEKLZZQfBItQHY7IV6nDQXK6y273J4vCfhL5PX6z+VbSbTQGCETiKRFbqzIA)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were very close. I think you needed `declare module` not `declare namespace`. This works for me:

```js
import { z, ZodType } from 'zod';

const fieldIsRequired = true;

declare module 'zod' {
    export interface ZodType {
        makeOptional: (required: boolean)=> ZodType;
    }
}
// Add syntaxic sugar to the Zod schema
z.ZodType.prototype.makeOptional = function (required: boolean): ZodType {
    return required ? this : this.optional();
};

const entry2 =   
  z
    .string()
    .min(10)
    .max(100)
    .makeOptional(!fieldIsRequired);
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgLwDRwFoQCYBUCeYApnAL5wBmUEIcA5MjnQNwBQrAxhAHYDO8FYEQA22AJK8ASkQCOAV2BQi2OAF44MKHKJtW2Ih2EBDJXBA45wkgyaJWcB3CIAPSLDjBuMIlApGOJFh4hCQI9o4RIEYA1kQA8mAwwDxGwgBccAAUSvKKyhkARhAQVkbcAJSqAHyYOATEbBGkrM0A9K1wAILYKrz4XkbOwBxwvHIA5iYaEBoAFoE4oxzzUazIAHRB9UTrYNQwEDAh61GxCUkpwmqUctwcF9xZOQpK2IXFpRUZWyF2EUowORQR7PPIqAD8c2AvDgGRgs2h6wgiWS3FSmXKbFIui4fHgRC8UHwACZrg5wshwg51vwoJ5xhiqXATp5MgBGAAM5SZJ0G7I5XJ5p3iKMumQAhIIROIpLIXspMawgA)

### Notes

I figured this out by looking at the [Module Augmentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#module-augmentation) section of the typescript docs. I almost made a post saying it wasn't possible since the next section says something about merging classes, but then I noticed they were using `declare module`.